# Why circle is not shown even if I use drawPath() on canvas object?

Tags: android, canvas

I want to do some programming with 2D api, I did some coding but the thing is output not coming. my code bellow......

```
 public class GraphicprojectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }
    public class MyView extends View{
        public MyView(Context c1){
            super(c1);
        }
    }
    public void onDraw(Canvas c2){
        Path p1=new Path();
        Paint p2= new Paint();
        p2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        p1.addCircle(100, 100, 300, Direction.CW);
        c2.drawPath(p1, p2);
    }
}
```

There is no error in the logcat.. UR help would b appreciated .....

Answer (score 1):

Your onDraw method is outside the MyView class. You need to override MyView's onDraw method.

```
public class MyView extends View{
    public MyView(Context c1){
        super(c1);
    }
public void onDraw(Canvas c2){
    Path p1=new Path();
    Paint p2= new Paint();
    p2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    p1.addCircle(100, 100, 300, Direction.CW);
    c2.drawPath(p1, p2);
  }
}
```